# Another inequality for two complex numbers

Tags: inequality

Given two complex numbers $a$ and $b$, and $1<p<\infty$, show that 
$$
|a-b|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^p+|b|^p).
$$
I have check it in some concrete cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p\in (1,\infty )$ the function $f(x)=x^p$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$ so, by Jensen's Inequality,

$$\begin{align}
f(\frac{|a|+|b|}2) &\le \frac{f(|a|)+f(|b|)}2 \\
(\frac{|a|+|b|}2)^p &\le \frac{|a|^p+|b|^p}2 \\
(|a|+|b|)^p &\le 2^p\cdot\frac{|a|^p+|b|^p}2 \\
(|a|+|b|)^p &\le 2^{p-1}\cdot (|a|^p+|b|^p)
\end{align}$$
Your inequality follows from the triangle inequaltiy $|a-b| \le |a|+|b|$.